# Field content not showing in public view

Tags: 7, views

I didn't build the website, and I'm new to Drupal.

I've been asked to add a new field to an existing content type. I've added the field, and it shows up on the form for that content type, but the data entered into the form doesn't seem to translate through to the public view.

The site is Drupal 7 & and uses Views. I don't think it's the views module that's the problem, although I've played around a lot with that and learned mostly how that works. The reason I don't think it's the views module is that when I'm looking at the page with the "View" "Edit" tabs, it doesn't show up there either.

Comment: under the content type select the "Manage Display" option. and make sure the field is showing up in the relevant "view mode".

Comment: Thank you. I selected all the options under Customized display settings in Manage Display, Full content, teaser, etc. It didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Are you sure your new field isn't Disabled on the Manage Display (For full content)? Have you set Custom permissions on that field? What happens when you add that Field inside your Views, does it show up? When you Edit the node again, is the field value saved and not empty? Are you overriding node or other templates in your theme? Maybe the template only prints out selected fields and not the rest of the content.

Comment: Is it visibility problem? that means field value is not rendered, or is it a translation problem? that means field value is rendered but in original language instead of translation language.

Comment: prkos - Thank you for all the ideas. It's not manage display or custom permissions. The funny thing is, none of the fields for that content type appear inside the View for the content type. I think they must be controlled somewhere else, but not sure where else to look. There are no other Views that are related. If I edit the node, the field value is saved, not empty. Possibly it is happening in the theme. but when i use web developer to explore the elements of the page, the field values aren't translating to the div - the div is empty. Could this rule out the theme being the problem?